# php redirect/header(location) doesnt work on cgi

Tags: php, redirect, header, location, cgi

i have a problem concerning redirecting in php running on cgi-server. the problem is the cgi-server is ignoring the redirecting command some how, so no redirecting. to be clear: there is *no*  problem when i use the same script on apache.

okay now the details:
i am using the Header('Location:'.$URL) function to Redirect from one script to another. i have tried to use relative URL and complete URLs, but still it seems i haven't write a Redirect in the script.

for example i created a test-script with

```
#!/usr/bin/php54

<?php
header('location:http://www.google.com/');
exit();
?>
```

when i run the script on a Apache then i would be redirected to Google, on the cgi-server i will give me a blank page with no quellcode well... the Editor indicates me 2 lines but there were also empty.

there is also some other code stuff in the final script, but they are working fine on Apache *and* cgi. the only Problem now is the redirecting thats why i tested it in a short script and still it doesnt work without any other "troublemakers".

i have work with php for a couple years but now the first time on cgi. from my experience there shouldn't be a Problem on the php-side, but i really have no clue whats going on in cgi... so i guess there is a Problem there? some cgi Settings?

again: the Skript (see above) is working fine on Apache (without the first line #!...)  but on cgi it doesn't :-(

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this before, usually happens because there is no space between the redirect location and the semicolon of *location*.

Try :

```
#!/usr/bin/php54

<?php
   header('location: http://www.google.com/');
   exit();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer... i have tried it with the additional space, but still... doesn't work :-(

Comment: did you have a look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.force-redirect.php)?

Comment: the force-Redirect is switched off (order from serveradmin) so there shouldn't be any Problem with differentiating between Redirect or direct calling.

the site to which i was first redirecting is also working on cgi so there is no error why the redirecting shouldn't work either.

but did i understand you right, that you meant that there could be a forced_Redirect so i wasn't allowed to call the redirecting-page? if yes: again this is set off so this shouldn't be the Problem :-(

but thanks again for your fast answer and your effort... i really hope that the solution is that easy :) *desprate*

Comment: Okay... i give up... this Problem i have doesn't exists on my private Webspace... (but in that case im not quite sure if this really run on a cgi-Server, but well the first line doesn't Pop up, so the chances are high that i tried it on a cgi-space)

so this Problem will be moved to my serveradmin. -.-

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Location: http://example.com\n\n";
```